# "Invalid object name" when executing a query from a linked server on SQL

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server

I have created linked servers on SSMS before but I am having trouble with this particular server. The linked server has come back as successfully connected and I can see the available tables, however, when I do a simple select query it's as if it cannot locate any of the tables within the database.

Would anyone have any clue as to why i'm receiving this error ?

```
SELECT * FROM [AMP].[default].[Import_records]
```

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid object name 'AMP.default.Import_records'.
```

Comment: You should try your query in the below form.

    SELECT * FROM <linkedServerName>.<DatabaseName>.<SchemaName>.<TableName>

Comment: Because you have to use 4 part naming, not 3 when querying a linked server.

Comment: @SurajKumar there's no schema, reason why its a 3 part name rather than a 4 part name

Comment: @SeanLange If there's no schema, what is this replaced with ?

Comment: Check schema name.. SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() along with above two comments from Suraj & Sean

Comment: So what type of RDBMS type is the linked server you are connecting to, @user3396351 ? `[AMP].[default].[Import_records]` will refer to the table `Import_records`, on the schema `default` in the database `AMP` on the **local** instance.

Comment: @Larnu Basically its an ODBC Driver called FileMaker which i've created the linked server to

Comment: Every object has a schema. You can always skip it to use the default. So it would be something like [LinkedServer].[DatabaseName]..[ObjectName] Notice the two periods between database and object.

Comment: @SeanLange ```Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES" for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "AMP". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used.``` This is the error I get when I run that

Comment: You aren't even trying. Did you try looking up what causes that error? I suspect not since you posted the results 2 minutes after I suggested not specifying the schema name.

Comment: @SeanLange I had tried that already which was why I replied straight away, its connected to an ODBC called FileMaker so its not a normal SQL database which has a schema, so using a fullstop to bypass the schema name won't resolve it as it does not have a schema name as it's just a flat file essentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you would be better off with `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(N'AMP',N'SELECT * FROM default.Import_records')OQ;
```

You will be able to do this with 4 part naming, however, we're not getting the information we need to able be able to really answer with that solution.

Comment: ```The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation```. It now shows this error, so I probably need some permission granted before this query can work, but seeing as it's not giving me the original error i'll mark this as the answer.